# Make jsonSource for vtree

Tags: javascript

I wanted to use JavaScript vtree plugin. For this i made a jsonSource. But i only get first child.[image]

I have multiple class and under a campus have multiple class and so is section. My json is like this

```
[
    {
        "campus_id": "4",
        "campus_name": "Test Campus Name",
        "class_id": "11",
        "class_name": "STD - VIII",
        "section_id": "11",
        "section_name": "A"
    },
    {
        "campus_id": "4",
        "campus_name": "Test Campus Name",
        "class_id": "15",
        "class_name": "A' Level",
        "section_id": "15",
        "section_name": "A"
    },
    {
        "campus_id": "5",
        "campus_name": "Dhanmondi",
        "class_id": "6",
        "class_name": "STD - III",
        "section_id": "6",
        "section_name": "A"
    }
]
```

Here is how i made the jsonSource for vtree.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var json_data = <?php echo $json_data; ?>;
$.each(json_data, function(key,value){
    alert(value.section_id);
    var jsonSource = {
            tree: {
                id: "root",
                nodes: [{
                    id: "master",
                    title: "Select Campus",
                    hasChildren: true,
                    nodes: [{
                        id: value.campus_id,
                        title: value.campus_name,
                        hasChildren: true,
                        nodes: [{
                            id: value.class_id,
                            title: value.class_name,
                            hasChildren: true,
                            nodes: [{
                                id: "section_id",
                                title: value.section_name,
                                hasChildren: false,
                            }]
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            }
    };
  //initialisation
    var tree = Vtree.create({
        // mandatory
        container: jQuery("#treeContainer"),
        // mandatory
        dataSource: jsonSource,
        // mandatory
        plugins:["checkbox"],
        // otional. all parents will be open automatically.
        initiallyOpen: ["parent_1", "parent_2", "parent_3"],
        // optional. default value is true.
        displayCheckbox: true,
        // list of initially checked nodes
        initiallyChecked: ["child_1"],
        //optional. default value is 'checkParents'. Checking a node check all his parents automatically. In this case checking child_1 at initialisation checked all his parents.
        checkBehaviour: "checkParents",
        // optional. default value is 'checked'
        checkedClass: "checked",
        //optional. default value is 'uncheckChildren'. Unchecking a node uncheck all his children automatically
        uncheckBehaviour: "uncheckChildren",
        // a list of disabled nodes
        disabledCheckboxes: ["parent_3"],
        //optional. by default value is 'disableChildren'. in this case disabling parent_3 will disable automatically his children.
        disableBehaviour: "disableChildren",
        // optional. default value is "disabled". The class applied to disabled nodes.
        disabledClass: "disabled",
    });       
});
</script>
```

How can i get all the campus and existing classes and sections as child?